# non-interactive password change of nspawn container

Tags: systemd-nspawn

I want to change passwd of root of nspawn container, as I am creating container via ansible just after I created rootfs, as at very first it doesn't have any root password.

is it a good idea to change passwd by using [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) module to replace root line in `/etc/shadow` file ?

is there any other way too to update the password non-interactively ?

I have tried :

```
echo user:pass | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

but echo is not working, a I am getting execv() `failed: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passwd` works for this case. It has an option `--stdin`. Do not use `echo my-secret-password | passwd --stdin`, because `echo my-secret-password` may become visible if someone runs `ps`, or maybe even in a log file if you are unlucky.

```
#!/bin/sh

PASSWORD=...

passwd root --stdin <<EOF
$PASSWORD
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is working fine in host, even the echo one which I mentioned above is running fine too in host, but failing in nspawn container

Comment: my shadow file was messed up somehow, pwconv helped and its working now